# Send image via OpenTok signalling

Tags: ios, swift, session, opentok

I am using OpenTok SDK for having session connectivity between devices. I am able to send messages and text top devices connected in a session.

I have a requirement of sending image. Does OpenTok provide the feature for sending image in a session?

Answer (score 2):

Because of the size constraint of the signals that Aiham mentioned, I did some experimentation with using AWS S3 as an intermediary to store the file during the transfer. 
The basic workflow is:

1. Client A uploads file to S3.
2. Upon upload completion, Client A sends OpenTok signal to Client B indicating a file is available for download.
3. Upon receiving signal, Client B downloads file from S3.
4. A file is transferred.

Using this approach, the signal payload limit is not as much of an issue, since the only data being sent over the OpenTok session is what's needed to download the file from S3.

I wouldn't call it a complete solution, but it might be enough to get you started:

https://github.com/wobbals/S3FileSharing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data URI scheme to represent an image as base64 text and transmit it using the signaling API.

However please note you will only be able to send very small images as part of the signaling API as the size limit is 8KB

> The data property of the signal parameter is the data string you send with the message. This property is optional. If you omit it, the message will be sent without a data payload. The limit to the size of data is 8KB.

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs
- https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/signaling/js/#send_signal_to_client

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i have tried that, that is not possible actually because image size would be typically more than 8kb. So, please provide any other way for this. 

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot send any more data than 8KB per signal via the OpenTok platform. Please see wobbals' answer for an alternative method.